# LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB

Tags: sql-server, dtexec

I have this error:

> LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80004005 (Login timeout expired). The SQL statement that was issued has failed

And here is my code, what is wrong?

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(50); 
DECLARE @VendorID VARCHAR(50); 
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000); 
DECLARE @Local_File_FullPath VARCHAR(100);   

SET @FileName = 'Extgt_skinny_file.txt.pgp' 
Set @VendorID = 'ET' 

Select @Local_File_FullPath = dw03_path  FROM GMAC_META.dbo.VENDOR_XFER_METADATA where vendor_id = @VendorID 

SET @sql = 'dtexec /SQL "\EMAP_FTP_XFER_CHECK" /SET \Package.Variables[User::FileName].Properties[Value];"' 
+ @FileName+'" /SET \Package.Variables[Local_File_FullPath].Properties[Value];' 
+ @Local_File_FullPath+' /SERVER "hqgmdw02/dw_dev"   /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E'


 exec xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`GRANT exec ON xp_cmdshell TO '<somelogin>'`. Please refer to [xp_cmdshell (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx).

Check to see if you are using a 32-bit DTExec on a 64-bit machine.

Ensure that the users that will run the SSIS package have sufficient permissions. I take that you run is under SSIS in a SQL Server Agent or you might run it manually. The service account running SQL Agent and your account must have permissions to execute the job. Please see [Error in executing SSIS package through Agent](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/68de81bd-b9cf-46fc-a200-e4143c1d19c4#e9198db6-059f-411b-938a-584097f91a16)

Comment: Thanks But I found the issue it was a really stupid mistake but the error was falsely pointing to the permissions.The issue was that the instance had incorrect slash "hqgmdw02\dw_dev" and some quotes were wrong. The bottom line is DTEXEC can give misleading error messages.So focus on syntax and then actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP mentioned, the server routes (for parameter `/SERVER`) should use backslashes and not common slashes. The error being displayed is a little misleading for this occasion, as the login times out because the server path is incorrect.

So change

```
/SERVER "hqgmdw02/dw_dev"
```

for

```
/SERVER "hqgmdw02\dw_dev"
```